# I am trying to make an api request to another app in django but in the same project, how do i pass the url to my api view, local deployment is working

Tags: django, api

````
```
def getpk(request, pk):
    current_user = request.user
    obj = LetterBody.objects.get(id=pk)
    company = obj.company_details.short_code
    location = obj.company_details.location.short_code
    datetime = str(date.today())
    token = Token.objects.get(user=current_user.id)
    url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('create'))

    payload={
      'company':company,
      'location':location,
      'date':datetime
    }
    headers = {
    'Authorization': f'token {token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    if obj.reference_code:
    return redirect('letters')
    else:
    response =requests.request( 'POST',url, headers=headers, 
    data=json.dumps(payload))
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    objid =data.get('id')
    obj.reference_code = str(location) + "/" + company + "/" + str(datetime) + "/" + 
    str(objid)
    obj.save()
    return redirect('letter_detail', obj.id)
````

local production is working just fine but once i deploy the api is not working.create is the name to my create url in the api aplication